# From a set of keys of a given type, setting two instances accordingly of those keys lead to error type

Tags: typescript

Given the following situation:

```
type Dummy = {
  a: string,
  b: number
}

const a: Dummy = {
  a: "a",
  b: 1
}

const b: Dummy = {
  a: "b",
  b: 2
}

const problem = (keys: (keyof Dummy)[]) => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    a[key] = b[key]
  })
}
```

A **TS2322** occur, can't found the way to solve it. (or to describe it better with words).

Here's the full error: `Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Comment: You know that the the type of a[key] must be the same as the type of b[key]. However it looks like typescript doesn't know this (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `keyof dummy` is `'a' | 'b'`, *without distinguishing between them* - TypeScript isn't smart enough to infer that if `a[key]` refers to a string, `b[key]` will also refer to a property that can contain a string. (It currently sees that `b[key]` is `string | number`, which is not assignable to a value which may only be a string or a number, but not both.)

You need to use generics to type the key properly, so that the assignment is permitted:

```
const problem = <T extends keyof Dummy>(key: T) => {
  a[key] = b[key];
}
```

If you have an array of keys instead, consider using `Object.fromEntries` to create a partial object first, then use `Object.assign`:

```
const problem = (keys: (keyof Dummy)[]) => {
  const partial = Object.fromEntries(
      keys.map(key => [key, b[key]])
  );
  Object.assign(a, partial);
}
```

Comment: Right. I have complicated the problem with an array (unfortunately corresponding to my case). I guess that I could add x implementation where x is the number of keys of Dummy. But that would be sad... Maybe it can be possible through casting ? (didn't succeed)

Comment: This works. Nice. But I'm confused about why this works. `keyof Dummy` is converted to `'a' | 'b'`. By using generics, it is now converted to `T extends 'a' | 'b'`. Why does this help typescript with the problem that you mentioned ("TypeScript isn't smart enough to infer that if a[key] refers to a string, b[key] will also refer to a property that can contain a string.")

Comment: @VivekMaharajh It means that, inside the function, if `problem` is called with `'a'`, TypeScript will then be checking the type safety of ` a.a = b.a`; the exact value of the parameter gets passed through and checked. Without generics, the value is widened to `'a' | 'b'`, which isn't precise enough.

Comment: Relevant feature request: [microsoft/TypeScript#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693)